# new lookup column in dynamics crm online

Tags: entity, dynamics-crm, field, lookup, dynamics-crm-online

how can i create a new lookup column and add it to my opportunity entity in CRM? What i want to do is create a new field called Business Sector on the Opportunities Form which should contain lookup options eg Public Sector, FSI, Education , Telco, SME, Manufacturing etc.

Any ideas on how to do this are welcome.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an entity called Sector. Then, from the Sector entity, create a 1:N relationship with Opportunity.  Save.  Then open up the Opportunity entity; a lookup attribute should have been automatically created for you.  You can now open the Opportunity main form and add the lookup to it. Save. Publish.